# How to send e-mails via Gmail from Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, gmail

I'm using Dart language and this lib: https://pub.dev/packages/mailer to send mails via but i'm only receive this message:

```
"Authentication Failed (code: 535), response:
< 5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
< 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials b16-20020a9d7550000000b006b45be2fdc2sm3438416otl.65 - gsmtp"
```

```
 String username = "email@gmail.com";
  String password = "password";
  final smtpServer = gmail(username, password);

  // Configurações do remetente e destinatário
  final message = Message()
    ..from = Address(
      'profept.recuperacao@gmail.com',
      'ProfEPT recuperação de senhas',
    )
    ..recipients.add(destinatario)
    ..subject = "email subject"
    ..html = "email body";

  try {
    final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer);
    print('email send ${sendReport.mail}');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: $e');
  }
```

I Try everything that I can try.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Gmail password to connect to the google SMTP server

you need to use Oauth2 or enable 2fa and create an apps password